# Multiple annotations found at this line faces:flow-builder-services

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsf, spring-webflow

I configuring webflow-config.xml using eclipse

Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element 'faces:flow-builder-services' of schema namespace 'schema/faces'
always i have this problem

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces.xsd',
>   because 1) could not       find the document; 2) the document could not
>   be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .
>     - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'faces:flow-builder-services'.

Did someone found a sollution for this

[image]

Comment: Could you please post the whole XML config file?

Comment: Please do not confuse Spring Webflow with Spring MVC! JSF+Spring-MVC is an impossible combination. I fixed the wrong tagging.